# www.example.com does not work, but example.com does

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

This question could be posted on ServerFault as well, however there is definitely a coding element involved due to the rewrite rules in my web.config.  This is why the question does indeed have a home on SO.

I've recently deployed a website to a new server and have discovered that trying to access my site via `www.example.com` returns a 404 while `example.com` works just fine.  I'm not sure if this is an IIS configuration issue or with the rewrite rules I've specified in my `web.config`.

I have not redployed the site without the rules shown below to see if they are indeed the issue.  These rules were working fine while the site was hosted by DiscountASP.NET.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to NON-WWW" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.rsolberg.com$"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://rsolberg.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="Default Document" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)default.aspx"/>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I've also confirmed with GoDaddy that there is a WWW `cname` pointed to @.

**Working:**
http://rsolberg.com

**Not Working:**
http://www.rsolberg.com

Comment: Is your server listening on `www.rsolberg.com`? If not, then your redirection won't ever happen, since the server will never see requests for `www.`

Comment: @Seth: I'm guessing I typed in `rsolberg.com` without the www....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would confirm that IIS has both host headers (rsolberg.com and www.rsolbeg.com) listed for your site. Without the www version requests will make it to the correct web server but IIS won't serve the correct site and may be returning a generic 404 instead. I don't think the redirect/rewrite is involved at all as no 301/302s are getting sent.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem earlier, just delete the earlier CNAME. And try adding a new one as below

www.rsolberg.com CNAME --> rsolberg.com

- Ananth Ramasamy Meenachi www.msarm.com

Comment: You don't need to include your name and website in your replies - that is what your profile is for.